# Issues automating printer driver update (printer settings) and printer preferences in Win7, using a PS,cmd,vbs,etc script?

Tags: printer, powershell, cmd.exe, wmi, wmic

WMI can do it, but I have an issue, PCs are on, but logged off. If I try to run:

```
wmic /node:%strIP% printer where DeviceID="lp1" set DriverName="Lexmark Universal v2"
```

It fails with a message about a "generic failure". I RDP in and then run the same command from my end, and it works.  Powershell version I am using is older, so it does not have some of the printer cmdlets, and updating PS is currently out of the question.  Is there a way to remotely log someone in, without actually having to RDP in? Via PS, cmd, PSEXEC, etc?

The other avenue I've taken is using regedit, but I'm hitting some hicups with that, namely that I cannot figure out what to copy. In regedit, I can change the drivername and the setting that enable duplex and tray2 (in printer settings), but I cannot figure how to change the settings in printer preferences for printing double sided and doing so along the long edge.

What I did to figure out what to change, I did a find on the printer name in regedit as a data value and exported the keys before changing the settings. Then I exported it again AFTER changing the settings.  I then used `fc /c /a /u before.reg after.reg` to get the changes.  I chopped up the .reg to include only the changed values.  Running the .reg seems to change everything, but the print both sides, along the long edge settings. It is a lexmark printer, so I am wondering if maybe preferences for it are stored elsewhere.

My company recently changed security policies in that after 30mins of inactivity, a pc is logged off.  Can't perform these driver changes during regular hours, when pcs are NOT logged off, so as of now they have been getting performed overnight by RDPing in and doing pc by pc manually. I wouldn't even mind figuring out how to log someone in remotely, without ever RDPing in, so WMI can do its magic then.

I gave it a try using just Powershell:

```
$Str = Read-Host "Please select a store number [###] "
$PC = Read-Host "Please select a PC number [##] "

$PCNm = "0$Str-CCPC-$PC"

$lp1 = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $PCNm -Query "SELECT * from Win32_Printer Where DeviceID='lp1'"
$lp1.DriverName = "Lexmark Universal v2"
$lp1.Put()
```

It fails there too with a generic failure, when no one is logged onto the pc.  I can query WMI for properties, so WMI is working, but when I try to set values, it fails.  I verified with a `format-list -property drivername` it updated it fine, once I logged in via RDP and THEN ran the script.  Obviously I don't want to RDP in at all.  I did enable PSRemoting on the pc, just in case too, so I will try `invoke-command` next.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to remotely log someone in?

You can use `psexec` to run a remote command as a particular user.

```
psexec \\computer -u user -p psswd [options] command [arguments]
```

Try the following command:

```
psexec \\computer -u user -p psswd wmic /node:%strIP% printer where DeviceID="lp1" set DriverName="Lexmark Universal v2"
```

Notes:

- You might also want to look at the `@run_file` option (Run command on every computer listed in the text file specified)
- To run against all computers in the current domain enter `\\*` instead of `\\computer`

---

**Syntax**

> ```
> psexec \\computer[,computer[,..] [options] command [arguments]
>
> psexec @run_file [options] command [arguments]
> ```
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> computer   The computer on which psexec will run command.
>            Default = local system 
>            To run against all computers in the current domain enter "\\*"
> @run_file  Run command on every computer listed in the text file specified.
>
> command    Name of the program to execute
> ```

...

> ```
> -p psswd   Specify a password for user (optional). 
>            Passed as clear text.
>            If omitted, you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
>
> -u user    Specify a user name for login to remote computer(optional).
> ```

Source [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) - Execute a command-line process on a remote machine. Execute a command-line process on a remote machine.